# Control that is not focused is capturing key presses when another control is focused

Tags: winforms, textbox, user-controls, focus

I am writing a Windows Forms application. There are many TextBox in an user control. When that user control is shown after being hidden, and I focus on one Textbox and I begin typing, another Textbox that does not have focus gets all the key presses and Text appears on that Textbox. This happens for a few seconds after the user control gets shown, then everything turns back to normal. 
I have checked the Windows Message that the Textbox recieves and in fact it seems that the WM_KEYDOWN was sent to a Textbox that does not have focus.
Anyone knows why this might happen?

Comment: Coud you reproduce it in a clean project with a simple UserControl just having many textboxes? ([MCVE])

Comment: Are you *playing* with the Enter/Leave events somewhere? You're not using `LostFocus`/`GotFocus`, right? Or are you handling Key press events? Is the Control that *gets all the key presses* the one with the lowest TabIndex?  Post a sample of the code shows what events are triggered and code, if any, that uses some form of threading.

Comment: The problem occurs when I have a UserControl with multiple `TextBox`es. That user control calls `Select` on one of the `TextBox`es during `OnEnter`. When I click on a different `TextBox`, Winforms enters a state where both `TextBox`es are focused at the same time and goes crazy.